# Increment in global variable in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to make a function which will read the first 4 character of two strings and increment the counter K if they are identical.

```
ying = ('SamSAMAN')
yang = ('sasaban')
k = 0
j = 4
while k<j :
   if [ying[k].lower()] == [yang[k].lower()] :
      k+=1
print (k)
```

when i run the code above, it s not showing any error but its also not printing the value of K (which i intended to be 2, based on ying and yang)

I am not sure where i am doing this wrong. any alternatives ?

Comment: You have made k both the loop variable and the match counter.

Comment: What does this question have to do with global variables?

Comment: i was intending that k as global variable. pardon if i use wrong terms. should have put "conditional not working" or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

When you get to the third characters (`m` and `s`) they are not equal, so `k` doesn't get incremented.  Going back to the `while` loop, `k` is still less than `j` so the `if` statement runs again (with the same result as before -- `k` doesn't get incremeted) and you get trapped in an infinite loop.

A better way to write this would be something akin to:

```
j = 4
count = 0
for c1, c2 in zip(ying[:j], yang[:j):
    if c1.lower() == c2.lower():
        count += 1
print count
```

Comment: ah, you are correct. my logic is not working very well. Thanks for pointing that out !